# Auto Shrinks the image despite fixed layout in FLex Container?

Tags: next-images

Next IMAGE autoshrinks the image despite specifying fixed layout as you add more content to the other flex row element. Here's the example sanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-water-ecgqpc?file=/pages/index.js:495-513

Expected Behaviour is image size should be conserved at least in fixed layout mode, but the more text you add to the field label:

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "25rem",
          height: "10rem",
          background: "red",
          display: "flex"
        }}
      >
        <Image
          alt="Empty test"
          src="/avatar-02.jpg"
          height={160}
          width={160}
          layout="fixed"
          style={{ flexShrink: 0 }}
        />
        <label>
          Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem
          Ipsum
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the smaller image becomes. Can someone help me understand why is this happening?

How it looks after resizing:

[image]

How it should actually look since the layout is fixed image with fixed height and width:

[image]

Comment: codesandbox is working ? its throwing some error

Comment: Hmm NEXT Image error, huh, it works while creating the project but throws this error when recompiling it :/

Comment: anyway I think your image is not stretching as you expected is because of flexbox container.  so wrap image component with a div and may be add `flex: 1 1 auto;` to that div if still doesnt work.